# Load Image in Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragment in viewpager (LeftFragment, MidFragment and Right Fragment)
LeftFragment contain a listview, when clicking on listview item, an image will be loaded on MidFragment. I've encountered a bug and spent a lot of time but still unresolved. Here is my code:

LeftFragmnet

```
public class LeftFragment extends Fragment{
    private  ListView listView;
    private List<ParseObject> ob;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ListViewAdapter adapter;
    private List<School> schoollist = null;
    private View v;
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
    MidFragment midFragment = new MidFragment();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_fragment, container, false);
        initComponent();
        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
        return v;
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.lv_left);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mainActivity.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                School school = schoollist.get(position);
//                midFragment.index = Integer.parseInt(school.getIndex());
                midFragment.reloadData(Integer.parseInt(school.getIndex()));
            }
        });
    }

    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait a moment...");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            schoollist = new ArrayList<School>();
            try{
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("School");
                query.orderByAscending("index");
                ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject name : ob){
                    School map = new School();
                    map.setIndex(String.valueOf(name.get("index")));
                    map.setCount(String.valueOf(name.get("count")));
                    map.setName(String.valueOf(name.get("name")));
                    schoollist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), schoollist);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
}
```

MidFragment

```
public class MidFragment extends Fragment {
    //    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    private Context mContext;
    private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener;
    private ArrayList<ParseObject> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//          imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));
//          mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .build();
        animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mid_fragment, container, false);


        initComponent(view);
        mContext = container.getContext();
        return view;

    }

    private void initComponent(View view) {
        mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video);
        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        mVideoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
//        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
//        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait a moment...");
//        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
//        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    }

    public void reloadData(int index){
//        mProgressDialog.show();
        objectList.clear();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Data");
        query.whereEqualTo("school",(Number)index);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                objectList = (ArrayList<ParseObject>) list;
//                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                if (!list.isEmpty())
                    openFirst();
            }
        });
    }


    private void openFirst(){
        ParseObject parseObject = objectList.get(0);
        ParseFile parseFile = parseObject.getParseFile("file");
        if (parseObject.getNumber("type") == (Number)1){

        }else{
//          mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//          mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageLoader.displayImage(parseFile.getUrl(), mImageView, options, animateFirstListener);
        }
    }
    private static class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

        static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            if (loadedImage != null) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
                if (firstDisplay) {
                    FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                    displayedImages.add(imageUri);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

layout MidFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

```
05-28 15:41:56.116  19297-19297/animuco.com.ckemi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: animuco.com.ckemi, PID: 19297
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: view must not be null
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware.ViewAware.<init>(ViewAware.java:70)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware.ViewAware.<init>(ViewAware.java:50)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.imageaware.ImageViewAware.<init>(ImageViewAware.java:44)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.displayImage(ImageLoader.java:365)
            at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.displayImage(ImageLoader.java:340)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.MidFragment.openFirst(MidFragment.java:119)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.MidFragment.access$200(MidFragment.java:36)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.MidFragment$3.done(MidFragment.java:101)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.MidFragment$3.done(MidFragment.java:95)
            at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:944)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

I'm not sure but I think the error is due to update the view of viewpager
sorry for my weak english
Thanks for the interest of the people

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code. IMO.

- Your fragment holds a reference to its activity, you already have one call getActivity().
- Left fragment holds a reference to Mid fragment - bad practice.
- On your RemoteDataTask you call super.onPreExecute() at your
  onPostExecute() method, its usually unimplemented but it may cause
  you errors in the future.

**And** to answer your question. You are initilyzing a new instance of MidFragment at your left fragment which isnt attached anywhere therfore MidFragment doesnt start his lifecycle and doesnt call onCreateView(). The Midfragment that LeftFragment is using isnt the same as the one that the ViewPager is using.

Comment: you can give yourself a more specific solution is not, I am very vague, this is my first project with android

Comment: Start with [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) and then read my answer again. if u have any more question. ill be happy to answer